# Assigning middleware inside a Middleware handle function in Laravel

Tags: laravel, middleware

I want to know If it is possible to assign a middleware or execute a middleware in handle function of another middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AuthTypeMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->header('auth_type') === "api") {
         // execute the auth:api middleware here
        }
        else {
         // execute the auth middleware here
        }
    }
}
```

I know we can achieve this by creating different route groups with prefix but still I wanted to know if their any possibility of getting this work

Comment: Why would you do this if you can just simply chain `middlewares` to a `route`?

Comment: Yes, I have already mentioned that this can be achieved by using different route groups, but my requirement is of creating multiple auth middleware that can be executed conditionally

Comment: Why not use `guards` instead?